# Logic Apps trigger Databricks notebook

Tags: triggers, databricks, azure-logic-apps

I have an issue. Is that possible for Logic Apps to trigger Databricks notebook in its pipeline?
I want to automate processing of downloaded files from Sharepoint and trigger notebook of Databricks.
Starting to build the custom logicapp connector but struggling according to this guide: https://medium.com/@poojaanilshinde/create-azure-logic-apps-custom-connector-for-azure-databricks-e51f4524ab27
Unfortunately struggling to create json Openapi file (image below)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Created a Databricks resource in Azure.

2. Created a Logic Apps Custom Connector resource with name Databricksconnector.
3. Once created clicked on edit option as shown below,
   [image]
4. Followed the document https://medium.com/@poojaanilshinde/create-azure-logic-apps-custom-connector-for-azure-databricks-e51f4524ab27
   by @ Pooja Shinde

and performed below steps.

5. Connector creation I have kept all with default values in this section.
   [image]
6. In General Information, selected scheme as **Https** and in host give data bricks url as **https://databricksinstancename.azuredatabricks.net**
   [image]
7. In Security, selected authentication as basic as shown below,
   [image]
8. In Definition tab, added new action by clicking on New action
   [image]
9. In General tab, provided Summary, Description, Operation ID and Visibility selected as none.
   [image]
10. In Request tab, Clicked on Import from sample.
    [image]
11. I am retrieving job details by passing job_id and details are,

Request Type: Get

Url: api/2.0/jobs/get?job_id=*******

Headers: Content-Type: application/ json

[image]

12.Click on import and request will be update as below,
[image]

13. Next click on Update connector and connector will be saved.
    [image]
14. Connector saved successfully as shown below,
    [image]
15. We can view all the provided details in json format by clicking on swagger editor,
    [image]
16. Now created a logic app with recurrence trigger.
    [image]
17. Able to see created custom connector as shown below,

[image]

18. Created connection for Azure data bricks as per the document https://medium.com/@poojaanilshinde/create-azure-logic-apps-custom-connector-for-azure-databricks-e51f4524ab27

[image]

19. Added parameter “job_id” and given value as shown below,

[image]
20. logic app ran successfully and able to get job details,

[image]

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/2.0/jobs?source=recommendations#--runs-list